# What did B-17 Pilots do?

Tags: b17-flying-fortress

Im making a game, and Im wondering what they did besides in combat, or bombing?
Futhermore, what did they do if they were in combat, and were heavily damaged?

Comment: They generally flew the planes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In combat, heavily damaged, they Aviatated, navigated, communicated.

Back on the ground, they are, rested, recovered, planned for the next flight. If lucky, maybe some recreation. If not so lucky, mourne for some dead comrades.